# Remove domain from email using linux substring bash

Tags: string, bash, email-address, parameter-expansion

I want to extract username from email. Example: johndoe@gmail.com
The domain will always be @gmail.com, but the length of username can be different
But I must use substring in linux bash (no grep, sed, cut, and others) like:

```
str="johndoe@gmail.com"
echo ${str:position:length}
```

OR maybe using loop like:

```
length=`expr length "$str"`
for ((i=0; i<$length; i++))
do
    echo ${str:$i:length}
done
```

The problem is, what should i write in the position and length. How do the code know if I it needs to extract all letters before '@'. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: For what it's worth, `expr` is basically superseded if you are writing Bash scripts. There are places in POSIX `sh` where you might still need it, but Bash has built-in functionality which replaces basically all of `expr`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of worrying about the position, remove everything from the `@` onward.

```
$ str="johndoe@gmail.com"
$ echo "${str%@*}"
johndoe
```

---

Sidenote: Normally it's best to use `printf '%s\n'` to safely print unknown data, but I'm assuming these are valid Gmail usernames, which are already safe, so `echo` is fine. The format is something like `[a-z0-9][a-z0-9.]{4,28}[a-z0-9]` (regex).

Comment: I think @ is a valid character in the name portion of an email address so I think you need to remove from the last @ onwards.

Comment: @Jerry This actually does remove from the last `@` onwards, but it's irrelevant for Gmail since `@` isn't valid in the username. Reference: [Create a username - Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/9211434?hl=en#) *"Usernames can contain letters (a-z), numbers (0-9), and periods (.)."*

Comment: I didn't notice that it removed from the last @ onwards so I shouldn't have mentioned it at all.  I guess it doesn't really matter anyway because https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Local-part says that @ can be in the "local-part" of an email address if it is in a portion that is a quoted string and I figure the odds of anyone using that are minuscule (non-existent?)

Comment: @JerryJeremiah There are many extremely hairy corner cases in what the RFC actually permits. Whether the OP's use case requires strict RFC conformance or not is unclear, but most real systems tend to ignore or reject a good deal of the dark corners which are technically permitted.

Comment: Maybe also point out why [quoting is important.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)